# Why is SocialAuth saying "facebook is not a provider or valid OpenId URL"?

Tags: java, coldfusion, railo, socialauth

Using [SocialAuth: v2.3](http://code.google.com/p/socialauth/) via [Railo CFML Engine](http://getrailo.org), I am getting the following exception thrown:

```
Railo 3.3.4.003 Error (org.brickred.socialauth.exception.SocialAuthException)
Message     facebook is not a provider or valid OpenId URL
Cause   org.brickred.socialauth.exception.SocialAuthException
Stacktrace  The Error Occurred in
/Users/rountrjf/Sites/ccpd-dev/controllers/socialauth.cfc: line 31

    29: manager.setSocialAuthConfig(config);
    30: successUrl = "http://dev.ccpd.uc.edu/socialauth/success";
    31: providerUrl = manager.getAuthenticationUrl("facebook", successUrl);
```

**Here is a snippet of my CFC code:**

```
public string function login() {
    id = params.key;
    configFile = expandPath("/SocialAuth/oauth_config.properties");
    inputFile = createObject("java","java.io.File").init(configFile);
    inputStream = createObject("java", "java.io.FileInputStream").init(inputFile);

    SocialAuthConfig = createObject("java","org.brickred.socialauth.SocialAuthConfig").init();
    config = SocialAuthConfig.getDefault();
    config.load(configFile);

    SocialAuthManager = createObject("java","org.brickred.socialauth.SocialAuthManager").init();
    manager = SocialAuthManager;
    manager.setSocialAuthConfig(config);
    successUrl = "http://dev.ccpd.uc.edu/socialauth/success";
    providerUrl = manager.getAuthenticationUrl("facebook", successUrl);
```

Why is it throwing this error?  The "configFile" has a property for "facebook" and it configured as shown in [step 3 of the "Getting Started" guide](http://code.google.com/p/socialauth/wiki/GettingStarted#Step_3._Implementation).

**CONFIG FILE I'M USING**

```
#google
www.google.com.consumer_key = opensource.brickred.com
www.google.com.consumer_secret = YC06FqhmCLWvtBg/O4W/aJfj
#you can set custom permission by using custom_permissions with provider prefix.
#www.google.com.custom_permissions = http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/,http://picasaweb.google.com/data/

#yahoo 
api.login.yahoo.com.consumer_key = dj0yJmk9VTdaSUVTU3RrWlRzJmQ9WVdrOWNtSjZNMFpITm1VbWNHbzlNQS0tJnM9Y29uc3VtZXJzZWNyZXQmeD1iMA--
api.login.yahoo.com.consumer_secret = 1db3d0b897dac60e151aa9e2499fcb2a6b474546

#twitter
twitter.com.consumer_key = E3hm7J9IQbWLijpiQG7W8Q
twitter.com.consumer_secret = SGKNuXyybt0iDdgsuzVbFHOaemV7V6pr0wKwbaT2MH0

#facebook
graph.facebook.com.consumer_key =       152190004803645
graph.facebook.com.consumer_secret = 64c94bd02180b0ade85889b44b2ba7c4
#you can set custom permission by using custom_permissions with provider prefix.
#graph.facebook.com.custom_permission = publish_stream,email,user_birthday,user_location,offline_access

#hotmail
consent.live.com.consumer_key = 000000004403D60E
consent.live.com.consumer_secret = cYqlii67pTvgPD4pdB7NUVC7L4MIHCcs

#AOL
api.screenname.aol.com.consumer_key = ab1QxoYXlT-x-ARL
api.screenname.aol.com.consumer_secret = 000

#LinkedIn
api.linkedin.com.consumer_key = 9-mmqg28fpMocVuAg87exH-RXKs70yms52GSFIqkZN25S3m96kdPGBbuSxdSBIyL
api.linkedin.com.consumer_secret = e6NBqhDYE1fX17RwYGW5vMp25Cvh7Sbw9t-zMYTIW_T5LytY5OwJ12snh_YftgE4

#MySpace
api.myspace.com.consumer_key = 29db395f5ee8426bb90b1db65c91c956
api.myspace.com.consumer_secret = 0fdccc829c474e42867e16b68cda37a4c4b7b08eda574fe6a959943e3e9be709

#FourSquare
foursquare.com.consumer_key = JQKEM1PHWFW4YF2YPEQBRRESXE3SBGNCYJWWDTZKF3IZNJ3V
foursquare.com.consumer_secret = 4IILLDFDVPP2LC554S4KXKETQNTDKPDSEVCKVHA2QEHKYBEQ

#Yammer
www.yammer.com.consumer_key=5zyIkp12TrkulSRbSegQ
www.yammer.com.consumer_secret=zUcCB9kqWhI1IiTAJbl9QdG2AWcUJMDWp3Qyv5VJJw

#Mendeley
api.mendeley.com.consumer_key=f31077a7576d5e02537e232eb649403c04fce1dd0
api.mendeley.com.consumer_secret=1810bc92d4625f673e4ff35cb248aab3

#Salesforce
login.salesforce.com.consumer_key = 3MVG9Y6d_Btp4xp4yFMR0tPSndkAVu4OBejuYcL2iGFC68tA49PknWKX20XdPl5s1iwWldyuAbSINWHbB2Jcu
login.salesforce.com.consumer_secret = 1993703471433041656
```

Comment: I don't know anything about SocialAuth, but the error message _"facebook is not a provider or valid OpenId URL"_ seems to be pretty explicit, so what's your question?

Comment: Okay, sorry about that - I added my question at the bottom.

Comment: It _"should be"_ configured as the guide shows, or it ***is*** configured as the guide shows? What happens if you specify the relevant URL instead?

Comment: Well, the guide is for general Java usage but I'm using ColdFusion so the code isn't 1:1...
Please see: http://code.google.com/p/socialauth/wiki/GettingStartedWithYourOwnFramework

Comment: So what do you have for the `#facebook` section of your file? Include the `#facebook` header and redact the key values so we don't see them :).

Comment: You're not using ColdFusion you're using Railo CFML.

The _call_ to manager.getAuthenticationUrl is 1:1 because it's a method call involving two strings.

The [**code where the error is thrown**](http://code.google.com/searchframe#YZcohgpbWlo/trunk/socialauth-core/src/org/brickred/socialauth/AuthProviderFactory.java&l=239) is straightforward - you need to end up with a string containing a valid URL. Therefore, if you're specifying just "facebook" this must somewhere be converted to a URL. Post your config where this is happening and/or change the value to Facebook's actual OpenID URL.

Comment: There's a [sample config file here](http://code.google.com/p/socialauth/wiki/SampleProperties) - what happens if you temporarily replace your one with that - does this error go away? If so, your config file is the issue, if not, something else is the issue.

Comment: @PeterBoughton The config file I'm using is the sample config file.  I didn't change one thing about it... :-\
Also, I say "ColdFusion" because that's the popular name for it, but Railo should behave very closely if not exactly the same as Adobe's in this aspect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using Constants.FACEBOOK which is actually "facebook" but in case it isn't it has a value that should work.

A possible reason that the error appears is that you are not using the correct input file.

Make sure that the configuration `config` is loaded correctly,
try to call `config.getProviderConfig(Constants.FACEBOOK)` and see if it returns `null`

Lastly you can try this. This is what I used and works.

```
SocialAuthConfig config = new SocialAuthConfig();
SocialAuthManager socialAuthManager = new SocialAuthManager();

config.load(inputStream);
socialAuthManager.setSocialAuthConfig(config);
```

I don't really know  Railo CFML Engine and what it does so I can't help.
Maybe remove `.getDefault()` from `config = SocialAuthConfig.getDefault();`?

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I edited the answer a bit to make it clearer. Thank you for the acceptance